# Laravel Eager Loading missing relationships when chained with first()/all()

Tags: laravel, eager-loading, eloquent, eager, laravel-3

Using L3 the following works fine :

```
$r = Site::with('services')->get()
```

That returns exactly what I'd expect. An array of `Site` objects, with the **services** relationship all neatly populated.

**However**, if instead I only use the following:

```
$r = Site::with('services')->first()
```

or

```
$r = Site::with('services')->all()
```

The relationships for the site object are complete empty.

That feels like a bug to me, but is there something off in what I'm trying to do? At the moment to get the same effect as using `first()` in place of `get()` I'm having to pull the first element from the returned array.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, using `->first()` *should work* as expected. Try it again, I have and it works. If it doesn't work for you, check your version. Mine is 3.2.10.

`->all()` is not supposed to work like that, it's just a simple shortcut. The [docs say](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#get) to retrieve an entire table, use the *static* `all` method. Note that it's a static method and you're using it in an object context. But anyway, you can just forget about that and use `->get()`, what's wrong with that?

And if you look at the source code `laravel/database/eloquent/model.php`, you'll see this:

```
public static function all()
{
    return with(new static)->query()->get();
}
```

As you can see, this function just creates a new `Model`, then retrieves all the rows.